# iPad : How to know Return key of iPad keyboard is pressed ? Please check image

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

I want to know that which method will be called when the following key is pressed.

[image: keyboard screenshot]

I want to start action on above key press.

How do I know this is pressed ?

Comment: FYI, return key on Apple product is enter key ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Observe the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And...

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}
```

You can also change it to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` if you need to be notified BEFORE the keyboard starts to disappear.

Comment: It's easily done, sometimes you become so engrossed in a project you forget the simple solutions! :)

Answer (score 5):

That's not a return key. Return key is the one above it. That's simply a button that dismisses the keyboard and you can't recognize it via standard text input methods. You need to register for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and implement that method:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // do whatever you want to do when keyboard dismiss button is tapped
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but you can try using notifications. Don't have Mac nearby atm, so just copy-pasting the code from github. I have that code in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and then 2 methods:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You should also remove the observer in viewWillDissapear, viewDidDissapear or elsewhere as observers are a big overhead.

Comment: @CW0007007 sorry, forgot to mention it

Answer (score 3):

Use keyboard hide `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification.

[Example.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html)