# View doesn't come back to normal position when 'little keyboard' button is clicked on the keyboard - iPad, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, keyboard

I have a view with 2 text box's for id and password. When the user tries to enter fields, view will move up and the keyboard will pop up. After clicking 'NEXT' pointer moves to the second text box, and when DONE is clicked everything goes back to normal position. Everything is working perfect until here.

But what's happening is, when i click on the little keyboard icon in the very bottonm right of the keyboard, keyboard is disappearing but the view stays in the same position and doesn't animate down.

[image]

I have the code for animating based on the initial position of the view

```
//Condition to execute when the keyboard is initially clicked
if (_pagerView.frame.origin.y == _pagerFrame.origin.y)

//Condition to execute when the 'Done' Button is clicked
if (_pagerView.frame.origin.y != _pagerFrame.origin.y)
```

What i need is, the view to come down to normal position when the little keyboard is clicked.Thanks

Comment: Removing the **if (notification.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification) and if (notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification)** made the view come back to normal position. May i ask, what's the importance of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification/HideNotification ?, will removing these statements cause anytime of error in future use?

Comment: i found the answer here 

[Return Key of iPad Pressed?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017324/ipad-how-to-know-return-key-of-ipad-keyboard-is-pressed-please-check-image